# How to set the alpha of the background color of a UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm currently making a custom button function but want to be able to set the alpha of the background color. This is what I have so far:

```
  func roundButtonCornersAndAddBorderColor(button: UIButton) {
    button.backgroundColor = .clear
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
  }
```

Comment: UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set the color with alpha use:

```
UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue:0, alpha: 1.0)
```

or:

```
 button.backgroundColor?.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks, by any chance do you know the values to produce black

Comment: yes, use: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue:0, alpha: 1.0)

Comment: @SwiftyJD @DiegoQ you can also use `UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)` for black and if a CGColor is needed just all `.cgColor` at the end. `UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor`

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 5 to set the alpha to 0.5 the code required is

```
button.alpha = 0.5
```

Comment: that make text and image of button alpha too